# Can't handle a JSON object properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm doing some tests at Angular.js, and already asked here a few things. Now, I found a strange error I can't find solution for; I hope you can do different!

It's pretty simple: I use this service to retrieve a JSON (haven't tested the test part yet, but the load works perfectly):

```
svcs.service('dataMod', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

    return{
        manage: manage
    }

    function manage(filename, action, data){
        var defered = $q.defer();
        var promise = defered.promise;

        if(action == "save"){
            $http.post(filename, data).then(function(){
                console.log("Data write success");
            }, function(){
                console.log("Error writing data");
            });
        }else{
            $http.get(filename)
                .success(function(data){
                    defered.resolve(data);
                    console.log("Data resolved");
                    console.log(">> "+JSON.stringify(data.regs));
                })
                .error(function(err){
                    defered.reject(err);
                });
            return promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

I inject it into my controllers' module and use it here:

```
$scope.data = dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load");
```

It works because when I check it with a console.log **to the $scope.data variable**, I get this in the browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za30X.png

So you may be asking... what's the problem? Well, normally I should iterate over this JSON in a way like this: $scope.data.regs[index].object_variable, no? Or just use a ng-repeat in a way like reg in data.regs. But it just won't work.

When I try to do a console.log($scope.data.regs), I get "undefined", and I've been trying various ways to get into the info, but I never can!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Manage takes three parameter.you are passing two parameters  dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load");

Comment: you send filename and data and data is undefined. Also data is over-scoped in the success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have misunderstood how promises work. Promises don't resolve itself to data so them to variables will not work.

> this will not work

```
$scope.data = dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load");
```

here the `$scope.data` is a promise from `dataMod.manage` so you could do `$scope.data.then(handler, handler).finally(handler)`

> this will

```
dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load").then(function(fileData){
  $scope.data = fileData
})
```

Although as mentioned by simalexan $http returns promise it self with two special callbacks `success` and `error`

```
svcs.service('dataMod', ['$http', '$q',
    function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            manage: manage
        }

        function manage(filename, action, data) {
            if(action == "save") {
                return $http.post(filename, data)
            } else {
                return $http.get(filename)
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

and then in controller

```
dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load").then(function(response){
  $scope.data = response.data //different object structure than for success, then receives the whole response together with headers, success receives only response.data
})
```

Comment: Thank you! Your correction over the use of the dataMod service worked for me.

Comment: But I'm still wondering why is $q used on the official development guide. What is it for, then? And why do they use it in conjuction with $http if it already brings promises in?

Comment: It might be personal preference, although I prefer `$q` over `$http` promise as it looks cleaner and you have more control over when to reject and when to resolve or use `notify` (i.e. file upload progress) and if you use breakpoints it's easier to debug with `$q`

Answer (score 1):

First:

There is no need to use `$q`, `deferred` and `promise`. You should just add a `return` before the `$http.get` and `$http.post`, as they are promises by themselves.

Second:

the `$http` success function returns a response with a `data` param.
so in your case you can check the returned data with `data.data.regs`

And at the end inside of success block just return it like:

`return data.data;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I saw in the official notes a complementary use of $q and $http, so I thought it was a good practice... so then, when should I use only $http, and when with $q? Secondly, no, it's not working; if I try to log the data.data.regs it says it's undefined.

Comment: I just tried doing the refered.resolve(data.regs) and now it's simpler, since the console.log($scope.data) now correctly shows the 3 objects. It's still not working on the ng-repeat tho

Comment: as @maurcy mentioned, in your controller you should set
`dataMod.manage("data/registries.json", "load").then(function(regs){
  $scope.data = regs;
})`

Comment: That's done! It worked perfectly :). But does nobody know the answer to that question about $q and $http?

Comment: `$q` you should use in cases:  
- multiple simultaneous promises (at the same time) - for example: you have `$q.all()`  
- customized promises  

`$http` is a service for standard http requests with integrated promises.
You should use it in almost all general cases: get, post, put, delete, head
One async request at a time